can't get basic express server to serve static js file
I am trying to create a basic Express server with an HTML and JS file. No matter what I try I can't seem to get the JS file to load.
index.js:
const express = require("express");
const app = express(); 
const path = require("path");

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Running on port 3000");
});

index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Express App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   Home page
   <script src="login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>

login.js:
function login () {
    return (
       <>
       <p>hi</p>
       </>
    )
};

No matter what I try I get some kind of error. Cannot GET, 404, or others.

Don’t know if it’s the problem but you set the static dir to “public” but don’t have that directory in the GH repo.

What URL are you navigating to that doesn't work, and what does your folder structure look like?

That's not valid JavaScript regardless. Guessing react?

Here's the ejs wiki for how you should set up your ejs-express app: https://github.com/mde/ejs/wiki/Using-EJS-with-Express

from the express docs: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

what does your folder structure look like?

Please keep index.html and index.js in public folder. Since public has now made the static files serving directory, this URL http://hostname:port/index.html will load the html file. And the browser  will load login.js as well since it is also available in the same folder. However, this js has jsx. Therefore on clicking this js file by viewing the html in developer tools,  the following error will be logged in console: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at login.js:3:5).

None of this matters as op is trying to run raw jsx. Unless I'm missing some new gh feature you need to build your react app to static files and deploy from there.

Is the issue still persisting ?

One of the options is to keep index.html and index.js in public folder.
Since public has now made the static files serving directory, the following URL will load the html file. And the browser will load login.js as well since it is now also available in the same folder.
hostname:port/index.html

However, this js file is a react component. The browser will fail to interpret it.
